# Panache Query with distinct returns PanacheQuery<Entity> and not ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm trying to get a distinct result of one Column from my Database with Panache+Hibernate. Normally in Hibernate you would get an `ArrayList<String>` back from the query.

```
List<String> list = repo
            .find("select DISTINCT(a.country) from TMdBrandAll a order by a.country")
            .page(Page.ofSize(1000)).list();
```

But if I try this Approach with Panache I get the ErrorMessage
[Comiler Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk0uy.png)

If I change the variable "list" to the returnType `List<TMdBrandAll>` the compile error is gone.

```
List<TMdBrandAll> list = brandAllRepo
            .find("select DISTINCT(a.country) from TMdBrandAll a order by a.country")
            .page(Page.ofSize(1000)).list();
```

When I now inspect the executed code in the debugger I get.
[Debugger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff88E.png)

How can I tell Panache that the outcome of the query will be an `ArrayList<Strings>` and not an `ArrayList<PanacheEntity>`?

Thanks for your answers

EDIT:
Code of Repo:

```
@RequestScoped
@Transactional
public class BrandAllRepo implements PanacheRepositoryBase<TMdBrandAll, Long> {


    public void updateBrand(String brandName, String soundexCode, String countryCode, Long active, Long isNew, String user, Long brandAllId) {

        update("set brandName = ?1, soundexCode = soundex(pkg_util.f_escape_special_char1(?2))," +
                " countryCode = ?3, active = ?4, isNew = ?5, modifiedAt = sysdate, modified_by = ?6 where brandAllId = ?7",
            brandName, soundexCode, countryCode, active, isNew, user, brandAllId);

    }

}
```

Working Code from Repo:

```
@Inject
EntityManager em;

public List<String> findCountries() {
    List<String> qres = em
        .createQuery("select DISTINCT(a.countryCode) from TMdBrandAll a order by a.countryCode", String.class)
        .getResultList();

    return new ArrayList<>(qres);
}
```

With injected EntityManager and standard hibernate query it works.

Comment: Please show the code of your repo

Comment: Updated with repo code

Comment: Hi. I am facing the same issue. But I am using Reactive Programming in my Quarkus app and I want to return a Uni<String>. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of Panache.

Have a look at the code https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/panache/hibernate-orm-panache/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/PanacheRepositoryBase.java

It always returns a List of the entity.

Either create a finder method in BrandAllRepo that returns a List of Strings or use an untyped list:

```
List list = brandAllRepo
        .find("select DISTINCT(a.country) from TMdBrandAll a order by a.country")
        .page(Page.ofSize(1000)).list();
```

You know that there will be Strings in the list.

The second option is not so nice. I would use the first option.

Comment: I think you could use Query Projections to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

I was running in the same problem, but I figured that it works if I use `.project(String.class)` and `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`:

```java
List<String> list = repo
            .find("select a.country from TMdBrandAll a " 
                   + "group by a.country "
                   + "order by a.country")
            .project(String.class) 
            .page(Page.ofSize(1000)).list();
```

It seems that Panache gets confused by the `DISTINCT` clause.

Comment: This answer solved my headache.